# Power series representation for $\frac{3}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I integrated to get $\frac{3}{1-x}$, turned it into a power series $3x^n$, and differentiated to get the series $3nx^{n-1}$ which is incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure $\Sigma 3nx^{n-1}$ is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%203/%281-x%29%5E2) agrees with you that $\frac 3{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3nx^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Shift the index:
$$
\frac{3}{(1 - x)^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 3nx^{n - 1} = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} 3(m + 1)x^m.
$$

(Here we've let $m = n - 1$, so $n = m + 1$.)